# AttributeError on Python with an encapsulation. Object hasn´t got an attribute...but yes it has it

Tags: python, python-3.x

i´m having an attribute error on my code when i try to encapsulate a variable and i cant see why.

```
class Car():

    def __init__(self):

       self.__doors=4
       self.sizeChasis=250
       self.colorChasis=120
       self.running=False

    def start(self,letsgo):
        self.running=letsgo

        if(self.running):
            return "Car is on"
        else:
            return "Car is off"

    def state(self):
        print("The car has ", self.__doors, "doors. And ", self.sizeChasis, "and ", self.colorChasis)

myCar=Car()

print("A: ",myCar.sizeChasis)
print("B: ", myCar.__doors, "doors")

print(myCar.start(True))
myCar.state()
```

And here is the error:

```
rint("B: ", myCar.__doors, "doors")
AttributeError: 'Car' object has no attribute '__doors'
```

Probably is an easy question but i cant see the solution.

Thanks

Comment: `__door` doesn't (really) exist, due to [name mangling](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#index-5).

Comment: Thanks, it has been very useful !

Answer (score 0):

When you have two underscores in front of a variable in a class, it is a "private variable", meaning you can't use it outside of the class. To fix this, remove the two underscores:

```
class Car():

    def __init__(self):

       self.doors=4
       self.sizeChasis=250
       self.colorChasis=120
       self.running=False

    def start(self,letsgo):
        self.running=letsgo

        if(self.running):
            return "Car is on"
        else:
            return "Car is off"

    def state(self):
        print("The car has ", self.doors, "doors. And ", self.sizeChasis, "and ", self.colorChasis)

myCar=Car()

print("A: ",myCar.sizeChasis)
print("B: ", myCar.doors, "doors")

print(myCar.start(True))
myCar.state()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer !